# Wordpress offset not working in custom WP_QUERY

Tags: wordpress

I'm coding my home page template (front-page.php) and I want the most recent post featured and show the following 5 posts right after.
For that, I created two querys:

```
// Query that gets the most recent post only
$args = array( 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'offset' => 0, 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date' );

$query = new  WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  
    // .........
 
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query
endif;

// Query that gets 5 most recent posts except the first one
$args = array( 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset' => 1, 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date' );

$query = new  WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  
    // .........

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query
endif;
```

The second loop brings 6 posts (not 5 as needed) and ignore the offset bringing the most recent post also.

It seems that the offset is not working at all.

If I change the first loop to include an offset (just for testing) it also ignores the offset completly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tested your code and it works … so there is something else that is making trouble…